Cannot verify digital signature using go-ethereum
I am building a dapp with wallet authentication from scratch for that client will generate digital signature using its private key and a message from server. Then the server will verify the digital signature by decoding the digital signature with the same message that was sent by the server to client and extracting the public key.
The problem is I am able to generate the client side digital signature but my code to verify it is not working.
I need help please
Code for generating digital signature on client side:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("ENV_PRIVATE_KEY")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
        message := "Please sign this message for address 0xc147d85E9E038178d2F789Ae1A10635A8984D324:\n1718665517938"
    data := []byte(message)
    hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(data)
    fmt.Println(hash.Hex()) // eg: 0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8

    signature, err := crypto.Sign(hash.Bytes(), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(signature)) // eg: 0x789a80053e4927d0a898db8e065e948f5cf086e32f9ccaa54c1908e22ac430c62621578113ddbb62d509bf6049b8fb544ab06d36f916685a2eb8e57ffadde02301
}


My attempt(failing/giving error even though correct parameters) - Code for verifying the digital signature and extract public key from it
package handler

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

var ErrDecodingPubKey          = errors.New("error decoding public key string")

// function to verify digital signature using a unique message
// uses secp256k1 with ECDSA.
func verifySignature(message string, signature string, publicKeyStr string) (bool, error) {
    // Compute the Keccak256 hash of the message
    data := []byte(message)
    fmt.Println("Message:", data)
    hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(data)
    fmt.Println("Hash:", hash.Hex())

    // Convert the signature from its hexadecimal representation (including the 0x prefix)
    sigBytes := common.FromHex(signature)
    fmt.Println("Signature Bytes:", sigBytes)

    // Recover the public key from the signature (handles the 0x prefix)
    sigPublicKey, err := crypto.Ecrecover(hash.Bytes(), sigBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to recover public key:", err)
        return false, err
    }

    // Parse the provided public key from its hexadecimal representation to bytes
    publicKeyBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(strings.TrimPrefix(publicKeyStr, "0x"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to decode public key:", err)
        return false, ErrDecodingPubKey
    }
    fmt.Println("Public Key Bytes:", publicKeyBytes)

    // Check if the recovered public key matches the provided public key
    matches := bytes.Equal(sigPublicKey, publicKeyBytes)
    fmt.Println("Public Key Match:", matches)

    return matches, nil
}

Does anyone know how to verify the signature properly?
logs -
Message: [80 108 101 97 115 101 32 115 105 103 110 32 116 104 105 115 32 109 101 115 115 97 103 101 32 102 111 114 32 97 100 100 114 101 115 115 32 48 120 99 49 52 55 100 56 53 69 57 69 48 51 56 49 55 56 100 50 70 55 56 57 65 101 49 65 49 48 54 51 53 65 56 57 56 52 68 51 50 52 58 10 49 55 49 56 54 54 53 53 49 55 57 51 56]

Hash: 0x257c52f4f04633e244a35543fc448b7bd8e000337c3f8feb7b6c4c3ab6041c00

Signature Bytes: [215 173 241 43 35 253 150 69 241 64 208 201 144 241 82 206 159 138 70 2 144 194 89 247 153 52 73 16 29 125 186 1 126 122 21 85 114 1 197 221 233 24 44 70 9 102 150 26 222 254 140 203 159 160 170 5 132 22 58 208 122 238 44 135 0]

Failed to recover public key: 


So the problem is that crypto.Ecrecover is both failing and not returning an error? Can you link to the Ecrecover documentation please? I can't find it from a quick search. Does the signature recover & verify logic work if you call it in your signing code immediately after you've generated the signature? Are the hashes the same in both?

"Recover the public key from the signature (handles the 0x prefix)" - I don't think you're using a string with an 0x prefix here?

You're also not showing us the publicKeyStr value in your logs, but it is failing before it gets that far.

I cannot reproduce this if I use my own key pair. Is your key pair for curve secp256k1 and do private and public key belong together? Post an example key pair for a repro.

@Topaco yes, my key pair are from my coinbase wallet which typically uses the secp256k1 elliptic curve for generating key pairs.
Also i can generate my public key back from my private key if thats what you are asking. So you can use your wallet key pair as well

But Topaco can't reproduce your problem with their wallet key pair.

As already mentioned, not reproducible with my key pair: Here https://go.dev/play/p/tvjh08_nNxh the signature is generated, and here https://go.dev/play/p/feI9GPx0H39 it is successfully verified.

@Rup https://goethereumbook.org/en/signature-verify/ this is the documentation i am using, it gives both for generating and verifying. But any other way would also work for me, I just know about this.
Also the digital signature being generated has the 0x prefix for the Ecrecover.

@Topaco damn its working for you so the code must be correct. I have to check again why it isnt working for me.

@Topaco Thank you so much guys I found the fault

Glad to hear it! If it's something that'd be useful to share please post an answer below.
